# Best way to transport data on MVC using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an Inbox with internal messages from my clients. When I click on the list over the name I'm requesting using jQuery `$.ajax` so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'messages/retrieve/' + client_id,
    }).done( function(data) {

        $('.messages-dialog').html(data);

    });
```

My controller should return a variable with json data? I understand it should dump it on a view and I should treat it there but how to do it if is client side?

I don't know if is better to treat and create the html structure into controller and than just load it in .messages-dialog with jQuery.html();

Sorry I'm a little lost on that issue.

Comment: the best practice would be to make your controller return a json containing all the data, then from jquery you simply parse the data and handle the creation of the view with javascript

Comment: @Cristian, why is that the "best practice"? Any creditable source for that?

Comment: well think about the fact that anytime you want to change the way your data is shown you don't have to touch any server-side code, it's enough to treat differently the data in the jquery script

Comment: You give more points to `html(...)` here and not to returned json data :)

Comment: It's up to you what you return, works either way

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.ajax() method, as in the example above. Also see the official documentation with examples http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Besides you can use jQuery.get() and jQuery.post() methods depending on how and what you will send. You can use this methods as shown below:

```
var url = 'messages/retrieve/' + client_id;
$.post( // for example 
    url,
    function( data ) {
        $('.messages-dialog').html(data);
    });
```

See official documentation with examples here: http://api.jquery.com/get/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

Server handler should be like as below:

```
use JsonResponse; // you must specify the exact component (I use this)

/**
 * Change message in dialog // for example
 */
public function changeDialogMessageAction(Request $request) {
    // request data processing

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array(
        // new data for returning to client
    ));

    return $response; // your data, which will be handled in callback
}
```

You shouldn't create HTML structure in the controller. It's bad style! JavaScript has asynchronous event model, and you should use it. Controller must handle / transform data, which were passed by you and then return back. jQuery callback must embed received handled / transformed data in DOM.

Comment: where's the data argument? Why Post ? Why not mention `$.getJson`?

Comment: 1) What argument? How do I know the context of its task? 2) Read attentively: // for example 3) There is no one word about JSON in his question!!!